# Configure exporter (Python prometheus_client) with multiple targets

Tags: python, prometheus

I'm creating my first prometheus exporter and I'm having problems using several targets in prometheus configuration.

I have created this exporter to get metrics from an API RESP service (json_exporter.py):

```
from prometheus_client import start_http_server
from prometheus_client.core import GaugeMetricFamily, REGISTRY
import json
import requests
import sys
import time

class JsonCollector(object):
  def __init__(self, endpoint):
    self._endpoint = endpoint

  def collect(self):
    # Fetch the JSON
    print(self._endpoint)
    response = json.loads(requests.get(self._endpoint).content.decode('UTF-8'))
    print(response)

    metric = GaugeMetricFamily(
        'my_metric_devices_status',
        'blah blah',
        labels=["device"])

    for p in response['devices']:
      host = p['host']
      status= p['status']
      metric.add_metric([host], float(status))

    yield metric


if __name__ == '__main__':
  # Usage: json_exporter.py port endpoint
  start_http_server(int(sys.argv[1]))
  REGISTRY.register(JsonCollector(sys.argv[2]))

  while True: time.sleep(1)
```

Then, I run the exporter:

```
python json_exporter.py 1234 http://my-rest-server:8000/api
```

I have this configuration in prometheus:

```
  ...

  - job_name: json
    scrape_interval: 30s
    scrape_timeout: 30s
    metrics_path: /probe
    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - my_target1
        - my_target2
        - my_target3

    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        target_label: __param_target
      - source_labels: [__param_target]
        target_label: instance
      - target_label: __address__
        replacement: localhost:1234 ## Location of the json exporter's real <hostname>:<port>
```

The problem is in my REST server I get three identincal queries to http://my-rest-server:8000/api (one http query for each target in prometheus.yml) but I can't pass the target parameter to de REST service because I don't know how I can get target parameter in json_exporter.py

Any help?

Comment: Do you know that there already is a [json exporter](https://github.com/prometheus-community/json_exporter)? I know this isn't the answer but maybe you can fit it into your needs, it looks similar.

Comment: It's developed in go and I couldn't installed it :(

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research, I change my original code to this one and it works fine:

json_exporter.py

```
from prometheus_client import Gauge, start_http_server, Counter, MetricsHandler
import json
import requests
import sys
from http.server import HTTPServer
import urllib.parse

REQUESTS = Counter('hello_worlds_total',
        'Hello Worlds requested.')
METRIC1 = Gauge('metric1', 'Testing1', ["label1"])
METRIC2 = Gauge('metric2', 'Testing2', ["label2"])

ENDPOINT = ""
PORT = ""

class MyRequestHandler(MetricsHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
      REQUESTS.inc()

      parsed_path = urllib.parse.urlsplit(self.path)
      query = urllib.parse.parse_qs(parsed_path.query)
      print(self.path, query)

      if("target" in query):
        host = query['target'][0]
        j = json.loads(requests.get(urllib.parse.urljoin(ENDPOINT, host)).content.decode('UTF-8'))
        METRIC1.clear()
        METRIC1.clear()
        METRIC1.labels(label1=j['label1']).set(j['value1'])
        METRIC2.labels(label2=j['label2']).set(j['value2'])
        return super(MyRequestHandler, self).do_GET()
      else:
        self.send_response(404)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(b"No target defined\n")

if __name__ == '__main__':
  # Usage: json_exporter.py port endpoint
  PORT = sys.argv[1]
  ENDPOINT = sys.argv[2]
  
  server_address = ('', int(PORT))
  HTTPServer(server_address, MyRequestHandler).serve_forever()
```

To run this code:

```
python json_exporter.py 8001 http://myjson-server:8000/
```

Comment: in case others need it, to enable collector mode for filtering only requested target, all you need is to add:
     
self.registry = CollectorRegistry(auto_describe=True)
self.registry.register(self)